# What is the possible mimetype hierarchy of an email message?

Tags: mime-types, html-email, email, email-validation

I'm working with a snippet of code that recursively calls itself and tries to pull out a MIME Type part of `text/html` from an email (if it exists) for further processing.

The "text/html" could exist inside other content such as `multipart/alternative`, so I'm trying to find out if there is a defined hierarchy for email MIME Types.

Anybody know if there is and what it is? i.e. what types can parent other types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, only multipart/ and message/ can parent other types (per RFC2046).

Answer (score 0):

Your question assumes that mail clients follow the RFC standards for MIME encoding, which they don't. I'd advise you collect a bunch of mail from sources and try and process it as-it-exists. The problem you are facing is extremely difficult (perhaps impossible) to solve 100%.